# Let $m(\partial A)=0$, show that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the boundary, $\partial A$, has Lebesgue measure $0$. Show that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

---

I got a bit confused on this exercise since I'm not sure which approach to use to prove that a set is Lebesgue measurable. This is my attempt:

$$A = int(A) \cup (\partial A \cap A) \quad\text{so we don't have to worry if $A$ is open}$$
$$m(\partial A) = 0 \implies m(\partial A \cap A) = 0 $$

So then $m(A) = m(int(A))$ but $int(A)$ is an open set and hence Lebesgue measurable.

*Tangential question: is it possible to write proofs showing that a set is measurable because it is an element of the Lebesgue sigma-algebra? What is the generator of the Lebesgue sigma-algebra? Just all the close rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^d$?*

Comment: Maybe you could look at the set of discontinuities of $1_A$?

Comment: Proving that a set is in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra amounts to exactly the same thing as proving that a set is Lebesgue measurable. What you outlined in your question is the proof by decomposing your set into the union of a measure zero set with a set in the _Borel_ $\sigma$-algebra, which admits a topological characterisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B \subseteq \partial A$ be a set such that $A=A^{\circ} \cup B$. Notice that $A^{\circ}$ is measurable since it is open, and $m(B)=0$ (since is a subset of a set with measure zero). Therefore $A$ is measurable.

**NOTE:** $A^{\circ}$ denotates the interior of $A$.

Comment: That's just identical to my proof though, right?

Comment: Yes, but you put $B$ explicitly. You just needed to justify why $m(A \cap \partial A)=0$. :)